# Changing line height and line thickness with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-spacing, line

I would like to change the distance between successive lines (height distance here 1cm) and also the thickness of lines using the code below if that's possible.

I need the reference number and page to be indented as in my MWE for the header.
I can change the colour and the opacity. I would like a page of lines that I change line height distance, line opacity, line thickness, and line colour in a simple code if that's possible

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath} % need for fractions
\usepackage{amssymb}%need this for square boxes
\usepackage{mathptmx}% this for heavy font also charter
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\pagestyle{head}
\usepackage{parskip}% this stops indent of first line in paragraph
\headrule % puts a line under the header
\header{ Reference number
}{ }{Page}

\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{left=0.4in ,right=1.5cm, top=0.6in,  bottom=0.75in}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    %\pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay   ]
        \foreach \i in {1,2,...,27}{ 
            \draw[lightgray,opacity=1 ] ($(current page.north west)+(0,-\i)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\i)$)           ;}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: The tickness of the lines is set by the [`line width`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#tikz/line:width) (default is `thin`, i.e. 0.4pt). The color is specified here by the `lightgray` but you can [change it](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#tikz/color). The distance between the lines is determined by the `\i`. Either change that to something different (be it `\i/3` or `\i in`) or change the [*y* vector](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#tikz/y) by specifying `y=.3333cm` or `y=1in`.

Comment: The question title is somewhat misleading.  Maybe rephrase it as "Using TikZ, how to change ..."

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I did try and play with the code I got from another website by trying various combinations and got no where with line width etc. because I didn't know where to put it in and everything I tried did not compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- I added two new length that can be set:

  - `\ymin` defines where the first line should be and
  - `\lineheight` defines the distance between two lines.
- `\ymax` is calculated to know how many lines must be drawn.
- The line thickness can be set with the option `line width=<length>`.

#### Code

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath} % need for fractions
\usepackage{amssymb}%need this for square boxes
\usepackage{mathptmx}% this for heavy font also charter
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\pagestyle{head}
\usepackage{parskip}% this stops indent of first line in paragraph
\headrule % puts a line under the header
\header{ Reference number
}{ }{Page}

\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{left=0.4in ,right=1.5cm, top=0.6in,  bottom=0.75in}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \newlength{\ymin}
    \newlength{\lineheight}
    \setlength{\lineheight}{7mm}
    \setlength{\ymin}{15mm}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{int((299mm - \ymin) / \lineheight)}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \foreach \i in {0, ..., \ymax}{ 
            \draw[lightgray, opacity=1, line width=.4pt] ($(current page.north west)+(0,-\ymin-\i*\lineheight)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\ymin-\i*\lineheight)$);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I needed the code, and I needed somebody like you to explain the code. Giving references to the Tikz manual is good, but unfortunately my Tikz skills are not sufficient enough to use this resource.

Comment: @Jon If you just start with TikZ you could read the chapter 2 Tutorials. They are very beginner-friendly.

Comment: Thanks, dexteritas,  can you give me a link so I know I've got the right chapter 2 Tutorials to read?

Comment: @Jon I meant Part 1 "Tutorials and Guidelines" of the [TikZ & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).